# How to split the values in a single index of an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist with its first index containing value "[00289853, S00174708]"
how can i split these values and get them separately?

ie, as value 1 = 00289853 and and value 2 = S00174708

I am using the below code:

```
List<List<String>> inputData = read.returnCSVArray();       

System.out.println(inputData.get(0));
```

Output:
[00289853, S00174708]

Comment: inputData.get(0).get(0), inputData.get(0).get(1)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of `inutData` you will see that it is defined as

```
List<List<String>> inputData
```

which means it is a list of `List<String>`

From your code you have already figured out that `get(0)` returns the `List<String>` so you could assign this to a value

```
List<String> values = inputData.get(0);
```

then based upon your existing knowledge you know that `values.get(0)` will return the first value and `values.get(1)` will return the second value

You could (preferably) use a loop

```
for (String val : values) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to separate ir because the values already store at nested List.

So when you want to access values, you just need to access by following example:

```
//print first value
System.out.println(inputData.get(0).get(0)); //Output as '00289853'

//print second value
System.out.println(inputData.get(0).get(1)); //Output as 'S00174708'
```

Comment: Thank you@Ronnie Tws ..saved the day :) used this approach